# Extensions for IEnumerable generic

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I've got two extensions for IEnumerable:

```
public static class IEnumerableGenericExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> InSetsOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int max)
    {
        List<T> toReturn = new List<T>(max);
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            toReturn.Add(item);
            if (toReturn.Count == max)
            {
                yield return toReturn;
                toReturn = new List<T>(max);
            }
        }
        if (toReturn.Any())
        {
            yield return toReturn;
        }
    }

    public static int IndexOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Predicate<T> searchPredicate)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var item in source)
            if (searchPredicate(item))
                return i;
            else
                i++;

        return -1;
    }
}
```

Then I write this code:

```
        Pages = history.InSetsOf<Message>(500);
        var index = Pages.IndexOf(x => x == Pages.ElementAt(0));
```

where 
    public class History : IEnumerable
But as a result I've got not '0' as I've expected, but '-1'. I cant understand - why so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write `Pages.IndexOf(x => x == Pages.ElementAt(0));`, you actually run  `InSetsOf` **many times**, due to [deferred execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx) (aka lazy). To expand:

- `Pages = history.InSetsOf<Message>(500)` - this line doesn't run `InSetsOf` at all.
- `Pages.IndexOf` - Iterates over `Pages`, so it starts executing `InSetsOf` once.
- `x == Pages.ElementAt(0)` - this executes `InSetsOf` again, once for every element in the collection of `Pages` (or at least until `searchPredicate` return true, which doesn't happen here).

Each time you run `InSetsOf` you create a **new list** (specifically, a new first list, because you use `ElementAt(0)`). These are two different objects, so comparison  of `==` between them fails.

An extremely simple fix would be to return a list, so `Pages` is not a deferred query, but a concrete collection:

```
Pages = history.InSetsOf<Message>(500).ToList();
```

Another option is to use [`SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx), though I'd recommend caching the first element anyway:

```
Pages = history.InSetsOf<Message>(500);
var firstPage = Pages.FirstOrDefault();
var index = Pages.IndexOf(x => x.SequenceEqual(firstPage));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've absolutely forgot about this LINQ peculiarity.

Comment: @Seekeer - No problem, happy to help! This is a nasty issue - it easy to make such mistakes. The worst part is when you *don't* see a bug, but the code seems to work well, but is in fact very slow. (aside from the bug, there's a great difference in the complexity with or without `ToList` here)

Comment: Yeah, I am starting to understand peoples, who don't like LINQ. By the way, can you recommend any good article/book on LINQ queries efficiency and optimizing?

Comment: @Seekeer - There is one I can think of. Jon Skeet had a long series of articles in which he [reimplements Linq to Objects](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/02/23/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-45-conclusion-and-list-of-posts.aspx), which I found very interesting. As for Linq: most complaints are against Linq-to-Sql being too slow. Linq-to-Objects can save a lot of code, IMO, it is worth "liking". Linq is a tool, and you should know when tools help you and when they get in your way.

Comment: Thanks for the information. "Аnd you should know when tools help you and when they get in your way" i thinks this words must be the motto of all developers.

Answer (score 1):

Does your class T implement the IComparable? If not, your equality check might be flawed, as the framework does not know exactly when T= T. You would also get by just overriding equals on your class T I would guess.